# Impossible to access an attribute ("flashBag") on a null variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this error when I use templating in service symfony 3.3 .. i have send email .. I use console commande for use service .. in file twig I did'nt use flashBag .. I use simple text .. code in twig never user flashbag or other code

[image]

code services.yml:

```
add_id_context:
    class: Context\ContextBundle\Services\ContextService
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
    public: true
```

code service:

```
    namespace Context\ContextBundle\Services;

    use ContextIO;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Recruiter;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

    Class ContextService 
    {

        /**
         * @var EntityManagerInterface
         */
        private $em;

        /**
         * @var \Swift_Mailer
         */
        private $mailer;

        /**
         * @var ContainerInterface
         */
        private $container;


         /**
         * construct ContextService.
         *
         * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
         *
         * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
         *
         * @param ContainerInterface $container
         */
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, ContainerInterface $container)
        {
            $this->em = $em;
            $this->mailer = $mailer;
            $this->container = $container;
        }

        /**
         * function AddIdContext
         */
        public function AddIdContext()
        {


                                    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                            ->setSubject('test validate')
                            ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
                            ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
                    ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:PublicController/Contextio:validateUser.html.twig'));
                            $this->mailer->send($message);


        } // end function
    }
```

console commande :

```
<?php 

    namespace AppBundle\Command;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;

    /**
     * Class ContextCommand
     */

    Class ContextCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this
                ->setName('recurit:add:context')
                ->setDescription('Add account context.');
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            $contextService = $this->getContainer()->get('add_id_context');
            $contextService->AddIdContext();
            $output->writeln(sprintf('successs'));
        }
    }
```

and file validateUser.html.twig content:

```
test send mail
```

how to resolve this error!!

Comment: please add the rest of the `AddIdContext()` function :)

Comment: and if possible the code in your command controller

Comment: @Liora this is function AddIdContext(); .. send email only and command is simple

Comment: Even if it is simple, I need to see it to understand what it does and be able to help you. The function you showed is missing the end of it.

Comment: @LioraHaydont I update my answer . i add code command and code services.yml of service

Comment: Thank you. The end of `AddIdContext()` is still missing tho

Comment: Also the constructor you are showing does not match your service definition.  As explained on the slack support channel, somewhere along the line you are trying to add a flash message to a session.  And sessions don't exist in commands.  It's possible you just looking at the wrong service class completely.

Comment: @Cerad .. i update my answer

Comment: Update your question with: validateUser.html.twig

Comment: @Cerad i update my anwser

Comment: Is your twig file really empty or did you perhaps forget to copy/paste it?

Comment: if you throw an exception at the start of `AddIdContext()` and then run you command, do you get your exception as the error message?

Comment: where are you using/reading  from session/flashbag ?

Comment: Run the command in debug mode by providing `-vvv` flag, it will show where the exception raise.